# How to calculate percentages based on 'weight'?

Tags: javascript, php, percentage

I would like to calculate/split percentages among an any number of people based on 'weights'.

Weight, in this case, is a modifier about how much does that person weigh in the splitting. We can set these weights before from 1 to 100, and the program should automatically split 100% between the people.

Here is the example what I'd like to achieve:

```
Person 1 'weight': 100
Person 2 'weight': 10
Person 3 'weight': 100
Person 4 'weight': 100
```

And the result I'd need is:

```
Person 1 : 32.26%
Person 2 : 3.23%
Person 3 : 32.26%
Person 4 : 32.26%
```

I know that it has something to do with proportions but can't think of how to calculate this. I'd like to do it inside a Javascript or PHP function.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Sum all the weight and then divide the weight with total weight and multiply with 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total of Weights = 310

Divide the weight with total weight(310) then multiply with 100